# Getting File Name without Extension

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-4

Here is my the syntax to get the Uploaded Filename with extension and Getting only the Extension

```
$name = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
$extension = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Here if i upload a file named `file.jpg`.Then i will get

```
$name = file.jpg
$extension = jpg
```

Is there any predefined way to get only the file name i.e., `file` without using any string replace.
If not kindly suggest a way to achieve in it str replace or any other way.

Answer (score 17):

As an alternative, if you do not want string operations you can use `pathinfo()`:

```
$name = 'file.jpg';
$file_name = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME); // file
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // jpg
```